# What exactly is an "extension" in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c

It's something different than a category, right?

Comment: Can you give us context as to what you mean by extension? I mean, where did you hear this?

Comment: The meaning of a word typically depends on the context in which it appears; not all developers or authors necessarily use the same terminology and developers may not always be precise or consistent with their use of terminology. Context can usually reveal whether the word was used loosely in a typical English meaning of the term or if the word was used as specific technical jargon. Please give the sentence or paragraph in which this was used as well as the author of that sentence (e.g. Apple's documentation is likely to be more strict in its use of terminology than a dev blog).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [The Objective-C Programming Language: Categories and Extensions](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/articles/occategories.html):

> A *category* allows you to add methods to an existing class—even to one to which you do not have the source. This is a powerful feature that allows you to extend the functionality of existing classes without subclassing. Using categories, you can also split the implementation of your own classes between several files. *Class extensions* are similar, but allow additional required API to be declared for a class in locations other than within the primary class `@interface` block.
>   [...]
>   *Class extensions* are like “anonymous” categories, except that the methods they declare must be implemented in the main `@implementation`  block for the corresponding class.